# How to get a list contains each element in a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am learning `tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface` and working on a demo with constraint that each weight be nonnegative.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tensorflow as tf

vector = tf.constant([.021,.046,.013], name='vector')
wt = tf.Variable([1./3,1./3,1./3], 'wt')

loss = -tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(vector,wt,'loss'))
equalities = [tf.reduce_sum(wt) - 1.]
inequalities = [wt[0],wt[1],wt[2]]

optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(loss, var_list=[wt], equalities=equalities, inequalities=inequalities, method='SLSQP')

with tf.Session() as session:
  session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  optimizer.minimize(session)
```

[ScipyOptimizerInterface](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/contrib.opt/other_functions_and_classes#ScipyOptimizerInterface)

> `equalities`: Optional list of equality constraint scalar Tensors to
>   be held equal to zero. `inequalities`: Optional list of inequality
>   constraint scalar Tensors to be kept nonnegative.

How can I change `inequalities = [wt[0],wt[1],wt[2]]` to something like `inequalities = [wt[i] for i in range(tf.size(weight))]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it with:

```
inequalities = [wt[i] for i in range(wt.get_shape()[0])]
```